# Alternative to __init__

Tags: python, class, instance, dynamicform

I have a Python class with the following `__init__` method:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        my_list = OrderedDict[
            (1, 'abc'),
            (2, 'def'),
            (3, 'ghi'),
        ]
```

I wanted to alter my_list with such function:

```
def process_my_list(self):
    new_list = self.my_list.__class__()
    for index, item in self.my_list.items():
        # process index or item
        new_list[index] = new_item
    self.my_list.clear()
    self.my_list.update(new_list)
```

I wanted to implement this for alteration of a steps’ list of a form. However, in case of dynamic form every step is separate instance, and thus `__init__` is called with every step. As a result, my_list always returns back to its previous state.
How can I update this list without it being restored? So far I’ve tried:

- passing the new list as a variable, but the ParentClass is complicated and this solution became a nightmare,
- making another attribute, but sooner or later I would have to declare it as a global variable for a whole class,
- making list of steps a property, but I’m just a beginner and fell in trap of infinite loop

Please help.

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking for.  A class attribute does not do what you need?  If not, why not?

Comment: Initially I’ve tried with class attribute my_list = get_list(), but sometimes other functions than get_list() had to change my_list, so it became a mess. Finally, it worked with combination of my_list as a class attribute, class method that alters it and passing the instance data (info about current form’s step) as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to make `my_list` a class attribute:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    my_list = OrderedDict([
        (1, 'abc'),
        (2, 'def'),
        (3, 'ghi')
    ])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def process_my_list(cls):
        new_list = OrderedDict()
        for index, item in cls.my_list.items():
            # process index or item
            new_list[index] = new_item
        cls.my_list = new_list
```

Comment: +1. I was thinking about classmethod, but the list of steps of forms dependent on instance data (i.e. info about current form’s step). It worked  with minor alterations.